# Grouping php array by value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array pulled back from a database that is ordered by number `([0]=>'',[1]=>''...etc)` within each element there are various associative values (title,date,area...etc). I need the array reordering so that all the elements with the same 'area' variable appear together. So effectively we will still have a `([0]=>'',[1]=>''...etc)` array but the first 5 or so will have the same 'area' then the next however many will have the same 'area' and so on.

To make it easier there are 4 possible values for the 'area' field (north,west,central,blyth valley).

What I dont want is a multi-dimensional array grouped by the 4 areas, I need it as one long array just in the order that puts all 'like' areas together.

Not sure if I've explained this as well as I possibly could but any help appreciated. If you need me to clear anything up just reply and I'll add appropriately.

Comment: You probably should be doing this in your SQL query instead of in PHP...

Comment: yeah I would usually do that but I dont have access to the query. I literally only get the array back as described above

Comment: Why don't you have access to it? Are you using a framework? Or?

Comment: wordpress, uses the get_posts function which has no argument for group by http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Could you use WP_Query? (Pretty sure it has ordering and grouping) Also you might be better off posting this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and explaining what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Also, I'm assuming "area" is stored in a custom field? You could then use "orderby = meta_value" and then set "metakey = area"?

Comment: it's a custom post type pulled back as an archive of posts the the wp core get_posts, I made the conscious decision to solve this at the php layer to negate risk off affecting other custom post types I have already in the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution...

```
$arr = array(
    '0' => array( 'area' => 'west' ),
    '2' => array( 'area' => 'north' ),
    '3' => array( 'area' => 'west' ),
    '4' => array( 'area' => 'central' ),
    '5' => array( 'area' => 'west' ),
    '6' => array( 'area' => 'north' )
);

$new = array();

// Get a list of possible areas
$areas = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ( ! in_array( $value['area'] , $areas ) ) {
        array_push( $areas, $value['area'] );
    }
}

// For each area...
foreach ($areas as $key => $area) {
    // Find a area that matches...
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ( $value['area'] == $area ) {
            array_push( $new, $value );
        }
    }
}
```

Also you may want to remove the first loop if there are only a set number of areas. Just fill the areas array with a list of possible areas in the order you want.

Answer (score 1):

Simply sort the array using a custom sort function with usort if you're unable to ORDER BY the field in SQL. Shouldn't be too much of a performance hit anyway, depending on the number of entries you have in the array.

```
usort($posts, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['area'], $b['area']); });
```

If you want a predetermined sort order, add a list of the different areas and their priorities:

```
$sortOrder = array(
    'north' => 100,
    'west' => 200,
    'central' => 300,
    'blyth valley' => 400,
);

usort($posts, function ($a, $b) use ($sortOrder) {
    if (isset($sortOrder[$a['area']], $sortOrder[$b['area']]))
    {
        return $b['area'] - $a['area'];
    }

    if (isset($sortOrder[$a['area']]))
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if (isset($sortOrder[$b['area']]))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});
```

You can remove the tests if you have a priority defined for all possible values of the 'area' field, although I'd suggest leaving it in since you'll probably be changing the possible values in the future.

Comment: What are $a and $b in this example? I get $a could be teh array of possible area strings and $posts is the array of posts that needs ordering but what is $b?

Comment: $a and $b are both entries from the $posts array - the two items that need to be compared to decide which of them is "larger" (to be sorted above the other). The function should return -1 / 0 / 1 depending on how the two items compare, which strcmp does by comparing the values of the two 'area' keys.

Comment: oh I was looking at it without the sort order. This first function u pasted in 

usort($posts, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['area'], $b['area']); });

Comment: Both functions are the same; the latter just use the $sortOrder as well (which is bound to the function / closure by using 'use ($sortOrder) so that it's available to the inner part of the function).

Comment: hmm, if I pass my array into 

usort($posts, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a['area'], $b['area']); });
all I get returned is 1

Comment: ha, nm that was me being dense. nice function. Can I accept both answers?